# Howto set maxlength of url name in Phalcon volt template?

Tags: url, phalcon, maxlength, volt

For example: I have next text

```
<h4><a href="http://somesite.com/video/{{ title.url }}">{{ title.text }}</a></h4>
```

..and need maxlength 10 chracters for the variables {{ title.text }} (not to be confused with font sizes)

Comment: A boring answer, but isn't that sort of logic supposed to be done outside of the view?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation is said tat you can add function to the volt engine.

If that is necessary in your case, you could use this:

```
$compiler->addFunction('strlen', 
    function($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs) use ($compiler) {

    $string= $compiler->expression($exprArgs[0]['expr']);

    $secondArgument = $compiler->expression($exprArgs[1]['expr']);

    return 'substr(' . $string . ', 0 ,' . $secondArgument . ')';
});
```

For further info:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#extending-volt

So in your case, after implementing this you could use:

```
<a href="http://url../{{ title.url }}">{{ strlen(title.text, 10) }}</a>
```